# Simulation in Simpy not working - yielded process never returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, simpy

I am trying to write a simple simulation of a queuing system:

1. An input process generates customers regularly at a specified rate.
2. A queuing system reacts when a customer is generated by the input process.

The input process is:

```
import simpy

class InputProcess(object):
    def __init__(self, env: simpy.Environment, name: str, freq: float):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.period = 1/freq
        self.counter = 0
        self.action = env.process(self.run())
    
    def create_cust(self):
        cust_name = f"{self.name}-{self.counter}"
        self.counter += 1
        return cust_name

    def run(self):
        while True:
            new_cust = self.create_cust()
            print("customer %s created at %d" % (new_cust.name, self.env.now))
            yield self.env.timeout(self.period, new_cust)
```

The process created out of `run` will emit an event every `period` units of time.

The queue:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from simpy import Environment
from simpy.events import AnyOf, Event

from input_process import InputProcess

class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self, env: Environment, period: float):
        self.env = env
        self.period = period
        self.inputs = []
        env.process(self.listen())

    def add_input(self, node: InputProcess):
        print("ADDED")
        self.inputs.append(node.action)

    def listen(self):
        while True:
            if len(self.inputs) > 0:
                print("YES")
                yield AnyOf(self.env, self.inputs)
                print("TRIGGERED")
```

The simulation:

```
import simpy

from input_process import InputProcess
from queue import Queue

def run():
    env = simpy.Environment()

    gen = InputProcess(env, "T1", 1/2)
    queue = Queue(env, 3)

    queue.add_input(gen)

    env.run(until=25)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

The output:

```
ADDED
traffic generator originated job 'T1-0' at 0
YES
traffic generator originated job 'T1-1' at 2
traffic generator originated job 'T1-2' at 4
traffic generator originated job 'T1-3' at 6
traffic generator originated job 'T1-4' at 8
traffic generator originated job 'T1-5' at 10
traffic generator originated job 'T1-6' at 12
traffic generator originated job 'T1-7' at 14
traffic generator originated job 'T1-8' at 16
traffic generator originated job 'T1-9' at 18
traffic generator originated job 'T1-10' at 20
traffic generator originated job 'T1-11' at 22
traffic generator originated job 'T1-12' at 24
```

#### The problem

As you can see, the queue tries to pause and wait for any input's events. In the current setting, there is only one input to the queue: the `InputProcess`.

Even though the simpy process of `InputProcess` does regularly yield events, the `Queue` never moves away from the `yield`, indicating that it keeps waiting for an event to be released by the `InputProcess`, but that process does regularly creates events.

I am not understanding what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one thing that is happening.

in InputProcess(object): the **init** the line

```
self.action = env.process(self.run())
```

creates a process and assigns it to your action property.

A process runs until it hits a return statement or gets to the end of the method.

Your run() method does not have a return, and your loop is infinite, so run() never exits.

Another point:
in the infinite loop of run(), you are creating a customer, creating a timeout() that you yield to, which means you wait till the timeout triggers/finish, then you loop.  The customers and the timeouts never get saved anywhere.

So here is a example of a process generator and a process, no queue needed.  This just demos one of many patterns for a simpy simulation

```
"""
Simple example of a process genterator

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

def a_call_back(env, cust):
    """
    shows how processes can call other stuff
    This is just a normal function and not a simpy process
    """

    print(f'{env.now} customer {cust} called a fuction')


def cust_proc(env, cust):
    """"
    Simple life of a customer
    """

    print(f'{env.now} customer {cust} has started doing stuff')

    # does some stuff
    yield env.timeout(random.triangular(1,3,9))

    print(f'{env.now} customer {cust} has finished doing stuff')

def gen_cust_processes(env):
    """
    Creates customers and starts their process
    """

    id = 0

    while True:
        id += 1
        cust = 'Customer: ' + str(id)

        # create a process, not no yield here
        proc = env.process(cust_proc(env, cust))

        # add call back, need lambda to customise 
        proc.callbacks.append((lambda e, c=cust: a_call_back(env, c)))

        # add some time between creates
        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(1,2,5))

# boot it up
env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(gen_cust_processes(env))

env.run(100)
```